# R code to change a column from datetime to time only

Tags: r

I am working with R, and have a column in datetime (2021-05-31 13:25:10) and I want to change it to time only (HH:MM:SS) by removing the date.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.ITime` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1$time <- as.ITime(df1$datetime)
```

---

If we need to get the `hours` only

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 <- df1 %>%
           mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime), 
           hours = hour(datetime), mins = minute(datetime),
           secs = second(datetime))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(datetime = "2021-05-31 13:25:10")
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! Keep in mind that I have a file (df1) and a column. It is the column I need to convert from datetime to hours/minitues/seconds.

Comment: @pancaldi Yes, I understand that.  If you check my post, I created the data 'df1' with a column named 'datetime' and the `as.ITime` is appied on the column extracted

Comment: @pancaldi I am guessing that you have read the data into R

Comment: @pancaldi i updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Comment: Ok, I understand now. 'Datetime' is the column. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi akrun,  suppose I have a number of columns in a dataset I want to modify, can I state this way: df %>% mutate_all(columnA, columnB, columnS=as.character) ??

Comment: You can do `df %>% mutate(across(c(columnA, columnB, columnS), as.character))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` to extract time component from date-time.

```
df <- data.frame(datetime = Sys.time() + sample(10))
df$time <- format(df$time, '%T')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I see that df is the file, but where should I refer the column I need to modify into hours only?.

Comment: `datetime` is the column name of your data ,you can replace it with your actual column name. To get hours from it you can use `df$hour <- format(df$hour, '%H')`